Inconsistent crs_transform in ERA5 Land Hourly for 2024 Causing Masking Misalignment in Google Earth Engine
I'm encountering an inconsistency in the crs_transform of ERA5 temperature data in Google Earth Engine, which is affecting the consistent application of a custom mask across dates.
I am using Hourly ERA5 Land dataset (ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY).
For January 11, 2024, the crs_transform is: [0.1, 0, -180.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]
with crs = EPSG:4326. However, for January 12, 2024, and onward, the crs_transform changes to: [0.1, 0, -360.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05] also with crs = EPSG:4326.
While both have the same CRS and pixel size, the shift in crs_transform values causes misalignment when using the same custom mask across these dates. Here’s a minimal example of my setup:
# Define area of interest
aoi = ee.FeatureCollection(...)  # Example AOI
select_band = ["temperature_2m"]

def get_era5_collection(dateIni, dateEnd, box, bandnames):
    era5 = (ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
            .filterBounds(box)
            .filterDate(ee.Date(dateIni), ee.Date(dateEnd))
            .select(bandnames))
    return era5

era5_jan_2024 = get_era5_collection('2024-01-11', '2024-01-12', aoi, select_band)
era5_feb_2024 = get_era5_collection('2024-02-12', '2024-02-13', aoi, select_band)

# Output for projection details
print("Jan 2024 Projection:", era5_jan_2024.first().projection().getInfo())
print("Feb 2024 Projection:", era5_feb_2024.first().projection().getInfo())

Output:
January 11, 2024 Projection:
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [0.1, 0, -180.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]}

February 12, 2024 Projection:
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [0.1, 0, -360.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]}

When I apply a custom mask (mask_1) with the same CRS to images for both dates, the mask only applies correctly for January 11, 2024. For dates in February, the output is either misaligned or empty.
mask_1 = custom_mask.neq(1)  # Sample custom mask

# Applying mask to ERA5 images
era5_jan_2024_masked = era5_jan_2024.first().updateMask(mask_1)
era5_feb_2024_masked = era5_feb_2024.first().updateMask(mask_1)

# Projection details after masking
print("Jan 2024 Masked:", era5_jan_2024_masked.projection().getInfo())
print("Feb 2024 Masked:", era5_feb_2024_masked.projection().getInfo())


Masked Projection Output:
January 11, 2024 (masked):
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [0.1, 0, -180.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]} 
{'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'temperature_2m', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'double'}, 'dimensions': [314, 99], 'origin': [2681, 383], 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'crs_transform': [0.1, 0, -180.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]}] ...


Masking works correctly, and the output has expected dimensions and alignment.
February 12, 2024 (masked):
{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [0.1, 0, -360.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]}
Feb 2024 Masked:  {'type': 'Image', 'bands': [{'id': 'temperature_2m', 'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'double'}, 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'crs_transform': [0.1, 0, -360.05, 0, -0.1, 90.05]}] ...

Masking fails, resulting in misalignment or empty images.
I have tried a lot reprojection steps but never get to resolve the issue. Is there any explanation for this shift in crs_transform origins in ERA5 data, or a recommended approach to enforce consistent alignment and masking across these dates?

Hi,
The difference is due to a GDAL library upgrade that changed how we read data from GRIB files. However, I'd like to understand the problem with the custom mask better. Could you post a complete example showing a problem?
Best,
Simon
